# How to have a password prompt on login but not on fast user switching?

Tags: macos, passwords, fast-user-switching

I want my computer to have some semblance of protection, so I want to have a login password. But after that, both my girlfriend and I use my computer and we want to be able to switch fast between the accounts.

Is there a way to disable the password prompt on fast user switching but not the one on login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, since it would defeat the purpose of user account protection on a multi-user system. If you enabled guest accounts, those guests would be able to fast-user-switch into your account, FileVault accounts would break, etc.

As far as I know, it's possible to set an Open Firmware Password using a utility on the OS X DVD, [but this only applies for non-default boot options](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1352) (boot into Bootcamp, boot into single-user mode). (article currently in maintenance, see [Google cached copy](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:oCwP1m2p1YQJ:support.apple.com/kb/ht1352+boot+password+mac&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=safari))

You could set up the username/password login screen instead of the list of users, and use nonobvious user names as "subsitute passwords". If you select the user name from the menubar icon, you are logged in/switched immediately. This is a really stupid idea from a security point of view, but it's the closest possible "solution".

Comment: That's a shame. My girlfriend and I use our own accounts for the convince of separating our files, open windows, synced account, etc., but we don't want the hassle of typing passwords to switch back and forth (this computer stays at home and is physically secured). But I still  want password protection for privileged access by programs, ssh, etc. Seems it can't be done :/

Comment: Why does it defeat the purpose? They could still let you use TouchID like they do after sleep or lock but no, you have to enter the password *every single time*.